# How to save html form data to firebase Realtime database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, forms, firebase-realtime-database

How to save HTML input in Firebase?
I tried all the tutorials nothing worked
this error is showing up

caught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/database". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

version 9.22.0

///code starts here/////

```
      <form action="" id="FRE">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" />
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input id="Email" type="email" />
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input id="phone" type="tel" />
        <label for="message">How you got injured</label>
        <textarea id="message" rows="6" cols="50" name="message"> </textarea>
        <br />
        <button onclick="writeData()">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

```
  <script type="module">

    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";

    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxTuP0X2PnJD5Z0AV4VE",
      authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxp.com",
      databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx85",
      appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx37e0cac8af4e14",
    };

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    function writeUserData() {
      alert(message);
      const db = getDatabase();
      set(ref(db, "users/" + "name"), {
        Username: document.getElementById("name").value,
        Email: document.getElementById("Email").value,
        Contact: document.getElementById("phone").value,
        Story: document.getElementById("message").value,
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: could you please provide the code sample you are uploading so that I can assist further? @mukul rawat

Comment: here you go @RobinaMirbahar

Comment: It seems that there is no path as `firebase/database`. You probably should import directly from the firebase script:
Try to replace this `import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";` with 
`import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-app.js";`.

Comment: thee requested module 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-app.js' does not provide an export named 'getDatabase'   @stolen_orange

Comment: the error message indicates that the import statement for the 'firebase-app' module is not correct, The correct URL for the 'firebase-app' module is in version 9.22.0.